# What does this chef cookbook code means

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I have following inside a recipe.

```
execute 'disable-all-yum-repos-centos' do
  command 'yum-config-manager --disable "*"'
  action :run
  only_if { centos? }
end
```

Now, what does this **{ centos? }** means here, is it a variable being called? or some inbuilt function,  as i learned,variables are called like node[variable name] or #{ node[variable name]} if inside a string,this above mentioned thing is new for me,help me to understand.

I understand that it's checking if the os is centos, but, what is this syntax? and how this is evaluated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a function call enclosed in a block. If you drop the block, Chef will call system command, you can see [more examples in the documentation](https://docs.chef.io/resource_common.html#not-if-examples).

It looks like your code is using [chef-sugar cookbook](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-sugar), `centos?` method is defined [here](https://github.com/sethvargo/chef-sugar/blob/master/lib/chef/sugar/platform.rb#L155).